# DataFrame: Transform a DF rows into a key with list of value pairs in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like below

```
id     name     value1   value2    value3
=======================================================
 1     AAA       1.0       1.5       1.8
 2     BBB       2.0       2.3       2.5
 3     CCC       3.0       3.6       3.7
```

I have convert the above df into something like below so that i can join it to another df based on name (which will be unique in my case)

```
name          value
=========================
AAA      [1.0, 1.5, 1.8]
BBB      [2.0, 2.3, 2.5]
CCC      [3.0, 3.6, 3.7]
```

Is there any way to achieve this instead of having too many looping statements.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, which applies function `list` to each row of columns `values` and then concatenates the two first columns of the original dataframe:

```
pd.concat([
    df.iloc[:, :2], 
    df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(list, axis=1).rename('value')], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   id name            value
0   1  AAA  [1.0, 1.5, 1.8]
1   2  BBB  [2.0, 2.3, 2.5]
2   3  CCC  [3.0, 3.6, 3.7]
```